# Как наложить одну гистограмму на другую в R?

Tags: r, гистограммы

Какие есть способы наложения одной гистограммы на другую помимо ггплота и параметра add=T в R?

Comment: А смысл? gglot или hist(h2, add=T) вполне достаточно

Comment: Можно использовать `lattice`, `plotly`, `rbokeh`, `ggvis`. Ключевой вопрос: зачем?

Answer (score 5):

В комментариях к вопросу справедливо спрашивают - "зачем?".

Если есть задача сравнить распределение переменной по каким-то группам, лучше использовать `geom_density`

```
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)

gg_dens <- ggplot(airquality)+
        geom_density(aes(x = Temp, color = factor(Month)))+
        scale_color_viridis(option = "B", discrete = T, end = .8)+
        theme_minimal()+
        theme(legend.position = c(.8,.8))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

На мой взгляд, еще удобнее визуально сравнивать накопленные распределения - empirical cumulative density (`stat_ecdf`).

```
gg_ecdf <- ggplot(airquality)+
        stat_ecdf(aes(x = Temp, color = factor(Month)))+
        scale_color_viridis(option = "B", discrete = T, end = .8)+
        theme_minimal()+
        theme(legend.position = c(.1,.8))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там про "помимо ggplot2" спрашивается, отсюда недоумение.

Comment: Действительно. Тогда еще сомнительнее, что вообще надо